# Excel VBA - Set SeriesCollection = 2D array

Tags: vba, excel, multidimensional-array, charts

I have a two dimensional array as follows

```
Dim plot() As Double
ReDim plot(0 to 1, 0 to arryLength) ' arryLength is some integer value
```

Dimension '0' refers to the x-axis values of a plot and dimension '1' refers to the y-axis values. I need to use this array to set the values on a pre-existing plot. I know with a 1D array you can do something like

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = xaxis()
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = yaxis()
```

How do I set it set `.XValues = plot(@ Dimension 0)` and `.Values = plot(@ Dimension 1)`?

Comment: You'd have to split your array into 2 single dimension arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe:

```
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("chart 1").Chart
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(plot, 0, 1))
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(plot, 0, 2))
End With
```

Comment: No luck. This will set `XValues = plot(0,0)` and `Values = plot(1,0)`

Comment: Have you tried it? It doesn't on my computer. Used like that, index returns an array

Comment: Yeah, I just tested it. I look at the series data on my chart and it only has a single data point. I think it is returning an array of one element.

Comment: Yeah, just re-read your question, try swapping the 0 and 1 and 0 and 2 respectively, it will return rows rather than columns then